# How do I remove partials in a Hash of Arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have this hash:

```
{"path_1" => [1,2,3], "path_2" => [1,4,5], "path_3" => [1,2,3,4]}
```

I want to remove all "partial" paths from the hash. So `path_1` will need to go because it's a partial of `path_3`; `[1,2,3]` is an "unfinished" array of `[1,2,3,4]`. All "partials" need to be removed from this hash.

Here is my current code that works, but it's slow when dealing with large hashes:

```
# hash sorted by length of value
hash_array = {"path_1" => [1,2,3], "path_2" => [1,4,5], "path_3" => [1,2,3,4]}
# make a separate copy of the hash
cloned_hash_array = hash_array.clone

hash_array.each {|path_index, path|
  # delete this path from the cloned hash so it doesn't match itself
  cloned_hash_array.delete(path_index)

  cloned_hash_array.each{|cloned_path_index, cloned_path|
    if cloned_path[0,path.length] == path.clone
      hash_array.delete(path_index)
    end
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just convention, but typically multi-line blocks use `do ... end` rather than `{ ... }` like you're doing with your `each`s.

Comment: Agree, multiline `{...}` blocks look weird :-)

Comment: Does order matter in these arrays, or are they more appropriately  Set?  If they are Sets, you could utilize Set#proper_subset

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, not wanting to start a debate, but... although I agree it's more common, I don't think it's always beneficial. I think a lot depends on previous language experience. Also the syntax highlighting in some editors works better with `{...}` than `do ... end`

Comment: @SimonMayer There's certainly no correct or incorrect way, I'm just saying the generally accepted convention. As for syntax highlighting… get a [better editor](http://www.vim.org/) `;)` (which actually nicely highlights `end`s differently based on whether they were paired with a `def`/`class` or `do`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how fast you want it to be and how many elements you have. You can try something like this (looks crazy but it's really fast):

```
scatter = 
  lambda { |tree, path, name|
    if path.empty?
      tree[:tag] = name
      tree[:path] unless tree.has_key?(:path)
    else
      head, *tail = path
      unless tree[:path].has_key?(head)
        tree[:path][head] = {:path => {}}
      end
      scatter[tree[:path][head], tail, name]
    end
  }

gather = 
  lambda { |tree|
    if tree[:path].empty?
      [[tree[:tag], []]]
    else
      tree[:path].map { |k, v|
        gather[v].map do |tag, path|
          [tag, [k] + path]
        end
      }.flatten(1)
    end
  }

scatter_gather =
  lambda { |paths|
    tree = {:path => {}}
    paths.each do |tag, path|
      scatter[tree, path, tag]
    end
    Hash[gather[tree]]
  }

scatter_gather["path_1" => [1,2,3], "path_2" => [1,4,5], "path_3" => [1,2,3,4]]
#=> {"path_2"=>[1, 4, 5], "path_3"=>[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: Victor, you're a genius. Although other methods worked too, this method is the fastest and returns correct results. Run through my hash in 109 seconds. A+

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, should be a little bit faster (there's no double loop).

```
h = {"path_1" => [1,2,3], "path_2" => [1,4,5], "path_3" => [1,2,3,4]}

h2 = {}

a = h.sort{|l, r| r[1] <=> l[1]}
puts a.inspect
# => [["path_2", [1, 4, 5]], ["path_3", [1, 2, 3, 4]], ["path_1", [1, 2, 3]]]

last_path = nil
a.each do |key, path|
  # now all paths are sorted in descending order. 
  # if a current path is a prefix for last_path, then discard it.
  # otherwise, write it to a result and start comparing next ones against it.
  if !last_path || last_path[0, path.length] != path
    h2[key] = path
    last_path = path
  end
end

puts h2.inspect
# => {"path_2"=>[1, 4, 5], "path_3"=>[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
hash_array = {"path_1" => [1,2,3], "path_2" => [1,4,5], "path_3" => [1,2,3,4]}
cloned_hash_array = hash_array.clone

cloned_hash_array.each do |key, value|

  hash_array.each do |key2, value2|
    if key != key2 and value.length <= value2.length
      if value.all? { |i| value2.include?(i) }
        cloned_hash_array.delete(key)
        break
      end
    end
  end
end

puts cloned_hash_array.inspect
```

Comment: Is this faster? It has 2 loops too so I don't know how much faster it is.

Comment: you are doing `path.clone`in your if that might be slowing things down. Try my answer out and see if its faster =)

Comment: `.clone` does not slow things down as much. It's the loop that's slow, I've already benchmarked it ;)